# .Net Framework websocket payload corruption

Tags: .net, websocket

I'm using the System.Net.WebSocket with .net framework 4.7.1 and 4.8.

Everything works great during normal operation but when sending a large number of messages (over 100 messages / second) the websocket connection starts sending corrupted payloads. Messages vary in size from 4kb to over 100kb.

Here is a screenshot from Fiddler:

[image]

From message 38765 things go wrong. That message is ok up to character 49139 and after that is malformed. The next messages that the connection sends are malformed as well and have a different frame type.

Has anybody experiences a similar issue? What could be causing it?

Comment: There is no .NET Framework 7.1. Do you perhaps mean 4.7.1?

Comment: Doh! Yes. I'll update the question

Comment: I think we are encountering a similar issue. I reflect messages through a NodeJs server, and find corruption reliably after 10k or so messages when sending random sized messages between 0 - 100k. The frequency of corruption appears to correlate with the buffer sizes (ClientWebSocket::Options::SetBuffer).

Comment: @sebf. I did find that increasing the buffer size to the max 64kb resolves the issue.